# Using preg_replace how can I inlude apostrophes and quotes

Tags: php

I need to correct the links in some HTML and I can use preg_replace but am stumped as to how to use quotes (") and apostrophe (') for example, replacing...

```
href=http://
href="http://
href='http://
href=/
href="/
href='/
```

Without including quotes it looks like...

```
$pattern = "href=http://";
$replacement = "href=http://example.com/test.php?go=http://";
$new = str_ireplace($pattern, $replacement, $html);
```

But how do to code **preg_replace** in this instance?

```
$pattern = "href=http://'";
$replacement = "href=http://example.com/test.php?go=http://";
```

Also, a prioritized loop through the $pattern will be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$pattern = "/href=['\"]{0,1}(\/|http:\/\/)/";
$replacement = "http://example.com/test.php?go=\\1";
$new = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $html);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. At first I didn't notice the change from str_replace to preg_replace. However I now need to refine it some more... some local links may not have "http://" and appear as <a href=index.html> so is it possible to include a condition statement that does not prepend a link that has already been replaced, ie: <a href=http://example.com>? The need for a separate routine is because the replaced text will be different.

Comment: `href=index.html` is not affected by the pattern. So just add your seperate routine afterwards. Or ask a new question to make it clear.